# Save settings in VS without quitting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, settings

I very rarely close down Visual Studio intentionally.  The project I'm working on is so ginormous that it takes about 15 minutes just to load it up, so it's been my practice just to leave the solution open overnight so that it'll be ready for me the next morning.  The only time I have to restart the program now is if it crashes - which - happens.  Every once in a while I'll do something it doesn't like and it quits on me.  I accept this.  I'd love for it to be bullet-proof, but I hardly expect that.

The downside of this is that apparently, any settings you change in the program while it's running (fonts and colors, keyboard shortcuts, auto-formatting settings, basically anything in the Tools/Options dialogue) are only saved when you quit the program legitimately.  These settings are **not** saved when it crashes.  So I find myself having to redo any settings changes I made every single time.

First off - why the heck doesn't it save the settings *when you change the settings*?  How hard would that be?  It's a certain level of hubris to take it on faith that your program will always close normally and not bother saving state until the shutdown process.  (And not having it save settings in an abnormal shutdown process either)  I'd get fired (or at least reprimanded) for writing code that did that, so how does Microsoft get away with it?  And is there some way of forcing it to save settings without quitting and reloading?

Comment: I have a solution that takes (not nearly 15 minutes, but) too long to open in VS 2010.  The last thing I do before I go to lunch (or coffee, or home for the night) is to close the program, reopen the solution, and lock my computer.

Comment: I generally use lunch/bathroom breaks for compiles - which take even longer.  You don't want to know.  There's some sense to your idea for going home at night, though it seems to me like it *shouldn't* be necessary by all rights.  Especially when the only goal is to make sure that user preferences are saved properly.  Just wish there was a more surefire solution to this.

Comment: Yeah, I use the water cooler for compiling, or else I check my e-mail or SO during the compilation.  If it helps at all, VS2012 is much quicker.  If I understand correctly, it's more multithreaded.  Have you looked at the macro editor, commands, and the like?

Comment: If it were forwards-compatible I'd consider it - problem is we'd have to get everyone in the company to upgrade or my 2012 version of the solution would not be readable by anyone who didn't upgrade.

Comment: But VS2012 is nominally backward-compatible.  It's supposed to be able to edit 2010 solutions without converting them.  I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Just remembering the pain of going from 2005 to 2008 to 2010.  With a project this large, something is bound to go horribly wrong.  I might try it if I can convince the higher-ups to get me a copy, but I don't want to rock the boat too much if there'll be any kind of compatibility issues.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman  VS 2012 is compatible with VS 2010.  Opening the project in 2012 doesn't prevent 2010 users from opening.

Comment: @WaltRitscher - I am using 2012 at home now, but at that job, it would've been weeks of requisitions to get them to allow me to use the updated software.  (Not to mention there were proprietary build tools that were built to use 2010 only, which somebody would probably have had to update.)  One of many reasons I don't work there anymore.  (Though not the most important one.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only thing you can do in your situation is to export your settings directly after you change them, and import them after a crash. This way your settings are safe, and you don't need to restart.

Comment: See, it should do that automatically, just as a matter of principle.  There's just no good reason to defer saving settings until shutdown, especially in a dev environment where crashes are likely.  This might be a valid workaround, but it really shouldn't be necessary.  (Though I'm not sure it'd work in all cases - the .vssettings file I think stores _some_ but definitely not all the settings, and you'd have to handle settings for 3rd party stuff separately, etc.  Kind of a pain to keep track of.)

Comment: I totally agree with you. But given the situation exporting and importing will give you the least pain.